# FPDF- FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file

Tags: php, fpdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file using FPDF, but it gives this error while getting executed.

> FPDF error: Some data has already been output, can't send PDF file
>   (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\nirman.siyaram.com\header.php:250)

The error happens to be in the `header.php` file where the `<?php` begins. I tried using ob_start, ob_end_clean and stuff like that. But it's not working.

```
////////THE PDF FILE/////////
<?php
$pdf = new FPDF();
global $DB;
$view=$_REQUEST['vbeln'];
require("fpdf/fpdf.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `" . $DB->pre . "party_outstanding_history` WHERE BELNR= '". $view ."'"; 
$rows = $DB->dbRow($sql);
$custCode= $rows['KUNNR'];
$docDate= $rows['AUGDT'];
$sql1 ="SELECT * FROM `" . $DB->pre . "party_master` WHERE KUNNR = '". $custCode."'";
$rows1 = $DB->dbRow($sql1);
$partyname = $rows1['NAME1'];
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Rect(5, 5, 200, 287);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica','B',12);
$pdf->Text(90,15,'JHAMPSTEAD DIVISION',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(70,20,'DEBIT/CREDIT NOTE',1,2,'C');
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica','',10);
$pdf->Text(10,35,'Doc No :',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(120,35,'Doc Date :',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(10,40,'Customer :',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(10,45,'Customer Name :',1,2,'C');
$pdf-> Ln();
$pdf->Text(10,60,'Agent :',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(10,65,'Reference :',1,2,'C');
$pdf->Text(10,70,'Text :',1,2,'C');
$pdf-> Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',9);
$pdf->SetXY(11,103);
$pdf->Cell(25,7,'BILL NO.',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'DATE',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'AMOUNT',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'LDAYS',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'EP1',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'EP2',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'INTDR1',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'INTAMT',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'NET',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf-> Ln();
$pdf-> Ln();
$pdf->SetX(11);
$pdf->Cell(47,7,'TOTAL',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetX(156);
$pdf->Cell(22,7,'Net Amt.',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->Cell(18,7,'',1,0,'L',0);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","8");
$pdf->SetXY (5,271);
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

//////////END//////////

/////////HEADER.PHP//////

```
<body>
<div style=" background-color: black; " id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="w3_close()" style="color:white;" class="closebtn">Close &times</a></li>
<ul class="panel panel1 panel-default" style="margin-left:-32px;">
<?php   /////LINE 250/////
echo getMenu("MAIN"); 
?> 
</ul>
</div>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" data-spy="affix">
<div class="navbar-header">
<a class="center" onclick="w3_open()" id="" style="font-size:20px;cursor:pointer"><span style="color:white;" class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></span></a>
<a class="navbar-brand pull-right" href="<?php echo SITEURL;?>/" title="logo"><img style="width:120px;height:30px;" src="<?php echo SITEURL; ?>/images/siyaram-logo.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<?php   if(isset($_COOKIE['PARTYCODE'])) { ?>
<div style="" class="topnav pull-right" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#" style="color:white;"><label style="margin:0px;">Welcome, <?php echo $_COOKIE['PARTYNAME'];?></label></a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunctionNew()">&#9776;</a>
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL."/mainform1/x-mainform1/"?>"><label style="color:white;">Profile</label><span class=""></span></a>
<a href="#"><label style="color:white;">FY :&nbsp;<?php if(date("m") > 3 ){echo date("Y")."-".(date("Y")+1); }else{ echo (date("Y")-1)."-".date("Y");}?></label></a>
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL."/cart/cart-detail/"?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" style="color:white;"></span><label style="color:white;">Cart</label></a>
<a href="<?php echo SITEURL;?>/?xAction=xLogout" title="logout"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off" style="color:white;"></span><label style="color:white;"> Logout</label></a>
</div>
<?php  }  ?>  
</nav>
</body>
  ///////END///////
```

/////////////FPDF.PHP////////////

```
function Output($dest='', $name='', $isUTF8=false)
{
    // Output PDF to some destination
    $this->Close();
    if(strlen($name)==1 && strlen($dest)!=1)
    {
        // Fix parameter order
        $tmp = $dest;
        $dest = $name;
        $name = $tmp;
    }
    if($dest=='')
        $dest = 'I';
    if($name=='')
        $name = 'doc.pdf';
    switch(strtoupper($dest))
    {                     //////LINE 996////////
        case 'I':
            // Send to standard output
            $this->_checkoutput();
            if(PHP_SAPI!='cli')
            {
                // We send to a browser
                header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
                header('Content-Disposition: inline; '.$this->_httpencode('filename',$name,$isUTF8));
                header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
            }
            echo $this->buffer;
            break;
        case 'D':
            // Download file
            $this->_checkoutput();
            header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; '.$this->_httpencode('filename',$name,$isUTF8));
            header('Cache-Control: private, max-age=0, must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            echo $this->buffer;
            break;
        case 'F':
            // Save to local file
            if(!file_put_contents($name,$this->buffer))
                $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
            break;
        case 'S':
            // Return as a string
            return $this->buffer;
        default:
            $this->Error('Incorrect output destination: '.$dest);
    }
    return '';
}
```

Comment: generate the pdf before the output

Comment: I don't get it. How?